# Make objects appear with count timer?

Tags: object, timer, coronasdk, transition

I have an object and want that to appear after ten seconds.

The code is:

```
function powerup(e)

    local rtran

    reloj.x=math.random(10,300)
    reloj.y=-70

    rtran=transition.to(reloj,{time=math.random (130000,140000),y=9000, onComplete=powerup})

end 

timer.performWithDelay(30000, powerup,0)
powerup()
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Please clarify your question, what objects do you want "appear" ? The code isn't clear enough to give clues about what you would like to achieve...

Comment: hi. thanks for answering.

the object that i want it to appear is "reloj";  with the transition.to it appears randomly since the beginning of the event, but i want it to apperar every "x" secs, for example: every ten seconds, and  since an especific time, not from the beginning. 
I think it can be done with a timer but I don´t know how. 

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
function powerup(e)
  local rtran
  reloj.x=math.random(10,300)
  reloj.y=-70
  rtran=transition.to(reloj,{time=math.random (130000,140000),y=9000}) -- removed the onComplete
end 

-- timer.performWithDelay(delay in milliseconds between function calls,function to call,how many times to call the function?)
-- 1 sec = 1000 milliseconds
timer.performWithDelay(1000, powerup,5)
```

The code above will call powerup function every 1 second for 5 times. Since you want timer.performWithDelay code to get executed after some time and not from beginning of application start, put it inside a function and call the function as shown below

```
local function launchAfterSomeTime()
  timer.performWithDelay(1000, powerup,5)
end

-- here delay is the delay you want before
-- you call launchAfterSomeTime function
timer.performWithDelay(delay,launchAfterSomeTime,1)
```

Don't forget to cancel the timers on scene exit if you are using storyBoard or composer API's

Hope this resolves your issue, happy coding!